# MVC design pattern in complex iPad app: is one fat controller acceptable?

Tags: cocoa, model-view-controller, ipad, ios

I am building a complex iPad application; think of it as a scrapbook. 
For the purpose of this question, let's consider a page with two images over it.
My main view displays my doc data rendered as a single UIImage; this because I need to do some global manipulation over them. This is my `DisplayView`.
When editing I need to instantiate an `EditorView` with my two images as subviews; this way I can interact with a single image, (rotate it, scale it, move it). When editing is triggered, I hide my `DisplayView` and show my `EditorView`.

In a iPhone app, I'd associate each main view (that is, a view filling the screen) to a view controller.
The problem is here there is just one view controller; I've considered passing the `EditorView` via a modal view controller, but it's not an option (there a complex layout with a mask covering everything and palettes over it; rebuilding it in the `EditorView` would create duplicate code).

Presently the `EditorView` incorporates some logic (loads data from the model, invokes some subviews for fine editing, saves data back to the model); `EditorView` subviews also incorporate some logic (I manipulate images and pass them back to the main `EditorView`). I feel this logic belongs more to a controller. On the other hand, I am not sure making my only view controller so fat a good idea.

What is the best, cocoa-ish implementation of such a class structure?
Feel free to ask for clarifications.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huge fat controllers are fine.

If necessary, just break off some "purely logical parts" from it and shove them in other "helper classes".  And use tricks like categories extensively where you can.

Definitely go with a HFC (huge fat controller) if that feels right.

Then, just get on your engineering bike and slim the hell out of it!

You should definitely not avoid the right structure, the good structure, the structure you want, just because one thing will be too big.

Just slim that big thing down by outsourcing concepts, going nuts with categories, etc etc - every trick in the book.

My belief!

Comment: The category tip makes perfect sense. I guess that's what I'll do, putt all the logic in the controller and factor out a number of categories for the palette, editor, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Some reasons to wrap a viewcontroller around your view:

- to use it in an Apple API that requires a viewcontroller (popover views, modal views, navigation bars, tab bars, ...)
- because the view can be invisible for a while, and so it makes sense to clean it up in low memory situations. The viewcontroller then guards the data that needs to survive such an unload-reload cycle.
- because you just like the MVC pattern

I think the second bullet justifies a viewcontroller for your editable content view and another one for your non-editable content view.

Comment: I do realize the MVC pattern is preferrable; but as I said I really cannot transition from my main viewcontrolloer to an `EditorViewController`, for the views layout and hierarchy is very very complex (a huge masking image is on top, a palette and a menu on top of it). This is why I was asking if I am missing something...

Comment: Kris, I guess there was something in the latest comment, after the colon, which has now disappeared; maybe a link?

Comment: Wanted to say: a viewcontroller for your fullscreen view (dealing with the palettes and when to go into edit mode and such). This controller needs a subview for the content. It would own an edit view controller, whose view is temporary used as the content view. When not in edit mode, this edit view controller is either released or only unloaded.